# Linux iptables DNAT on incoming packet without conntrack (stateless)

Tags: iptables

In my linux box `10.20.1.1`, i got two UDP apps binded on port `46000 (App A)` and `36000(App B)` respectively. The apps communicate with two UDP servers bindeded as `10.10.1.1:36000 (Srv X)` and `10.10.1.2:36000 (Srv Y)` respectively.

When i send the packet out i have a requirement to always use UDP src port as 36000. The packet on wire will be always `36000 - 36000` src and dst ports.

My iptables rules are like below. My intention is to `DNAT` the incoming packet from Srv X from port `36000 to 46000` so that App A receives it.

```
*nat
-A PREROUTING -s 10.10.1.1/32 -p udp --dport 36000 -j DNAT --to-destination :46000

*raw
-A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 36000 -j CT --notrack
-A PREROUTING -p udp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 36000 -j CT --notrack
-A OUTPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT

*filter

-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 36000 -j ACCEPT --> rule 1
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 46000 -j ACCEPT --> rule 2
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 36000 -j ACCEPT -> rule 3
```

When i send a packet out from `App A to Srv X` it goes fine. There is no conntrack entry in `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` and OUT packet matches `rule 3`. When the response comes from `Srv X to App A`, the packet traverses raw table but it `DOES NOT` undergo `DNAT` and directly jumps to filter table rule 1. This means Srv X response comes to my box but it goes to App B instead of App A.

**Questions**:

1. RAW table indicates there is no `CONNTRACK`. However, the above behaviour indicates the first packet `App A -> Srv X` with src and dst port as `36000 - 36000` is being tracked by some module somewhere. Hence the response from `Srv X -> App A` does not seem to undergo DNAT. How do i avoid this `CONNTRACK`?
2. How to ensure every incoming packet from Srv X with dst port 36000 always undergoes DNAT?

Thanks in advance,
Telex

Comment: There used to be a RAWDNAT and RAWSNAT target in xtables-addons. Now I believe their functionality has been absorbed by DNETMAP.

Comment: No, sorry, DNETMAP still uses conntrack.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the [Netfilter documentation](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//netfilter-hacking-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.3), it is said that ***"Connection tracking is fundamental to NAT"***, hence you cannot have DNAT without enabling **conntrack**.